# Form no action -> post using autopilot

Tags: html, forms

I am using an external program, "Autopilot" to essentially capture my form (For my marketers). However, I have made a form that does not require any "action" on post, eg, I don't want the page to go anywhere, instead I want #answer-button to act as a button which goes to the next question. (I have buttons before the form which go to the next question).

So my question is, how do I go about creating a form that doesn't reload the page, but still posts data using " action='something' "?

my code

```
<form id="email-gate-form" action="">
   <input type="text" placeholder="FIRST NAME" name="first-name" required>
   <input type="text" placeholder="LAST NAME" name="last-name" required>
   <input type="text" placeholder="EMAIL" name="email" required>
   <input type="text" placeholder="COMPANY" name="company" required>
   <input type="submit" value="GET MY RESULTS" name="submit" id="answer-button" class="question-form-gate">
 </form>
```

A small peak into my javascript

```
$("#answer-button").click(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
});

var emailGateButton = $("#email-gate .question-form-gate");
emailGateButton.on('click', function () {

questionsOverlay.show();
TweenMax.staggerTo("#email-gate .animated", 0.25, {opacity: 0}, 0.25, "-=0.5")
setTimeout(function(){
    emailGate.hide();
},1000)
setTimeout(function(){
    questionFinal.show();
    TweenMax.staggerFrom("#section-final .animated", 0.25, {opacity: 0}, 0.25, "-=0.5")
},1000)
setTimeout(function(){
    questionsOverlay.hide();
},3000);

});
```

any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<form id="email-gate-form" method="post">
    <input type="text" placeholder="FIRST NAME" name="first-name" required>
    <input type="text" placeholder="LAST NAME" name="last-name" required>
    <input type="text" placeholder="EMAIL" name="email" required>
    <input type="text" placeholder="COMPANY" name="company" required>
    <input type="submit" value="GET MY RESULTS" name="submit" id="answer-button" class="question-form-gate">
</form>

$("#email-gate-form").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    process_form();
});

function process_form() {
    var name = $("input[name=first-name]").val();
    console.log(name);
    // do whatever you need to do with your varables
}
```